# What does >> mean in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I recently saw that representation in here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method

'exponent := exponent >> 1'

what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a [right-shift](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx) operator.

Right-shifting a number by 1 is the same as dividing it by two.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like shift right (which effectively divides by two).

It's a bit odd that the example uses `mod` and `>>`. I'd expect `& 1` and `>> 1` or `mod 2` and `/ 2` for consistency

Comment: thanks! sorry will accept earlier posters answer but you're all correct. really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it can be right bit shift like in C. Please see this page for further explanation of this [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) operator.